# How to implement the Redis Rate Limiting in spring cloud gateway?

Tags: java, rate-limiting, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to set up the rate-limiting in a spring cloud gateway.

I tried to configure the filter in the application.yaml as below

```
filters:
    - name: RequestRateLimiter
      args:
         redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
         redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 5
```

I am getting the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name RequestRateLimiter
```

How to implement the rate limit in the spring cloud gateway?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities is not including the following dependency (the mistake which I did first time)

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive
```

Since the `args` contain `redis-rate-limiter` this dependency is must.

Below is a screenshot from the IDE showing `RequestRateLimiterGatewayFilterFactory` getting added when the above dependency is included.

[image]